# How do I create an object whose constructor accepts a method from another class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delegates

I'm trying to create an object which contains a call to a specific method in some other class. You should be able to trigger a call to that method from an instance of the object. As far as I've managed to figure out, the way of doing that would be a delegate. So is this a valid way of going around doing this? Wrapping a method from the class you want to use as a delegate, and then setting up your object like this?

```
public class ItemCombination
{
    public ItemCombination(string Item1, string Item2, Delegate interaction)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
        this.interaction = interaction;
    }

    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public Delegate interaction { get; set; }

    public void Interact()
    {
       interaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing in a callback is definitely a legitimate way to inject functionality. I would, however suggest a typed callback (for clarity; e.g. Action, Func<string>, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what delegates are for, however as already mentioned in the comments, you should use typed delegates, i.e. [`System.Action<T...>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) if the delegate has a `void` return type, or [`Func<T..., R>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) if it returns an instance of `R`. Your example would then look like this:

```
public class ItemCombination
{
    public ItemCombination(string Item1, string Item2, Action interaction)
    {
        this.Item1 = Item1;
        this.Item2 = Item2;
        this.interaction = interaction;
    }

    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public Action Interaction { get; set; }

    public void Interact()
    {
       // safeguard against null delegate
       Interaction?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, got it. And you could even directly invoke from the public field Interaction instead of making a method specifically for it?

Comment: Sure, that entirely depends on how much you want to encapsulate and safeguard your API. E.g. you could have a default implementation that you either set in the constructor if the `interaction` argument is `null`, or alternatively you call it inside your wrapper `Interact()` if the delegate is `null`.